# Searching the JS file you're In for string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, testing, testcafe

Okay, so this is a weird situation. I have a JS file with a string:

```
 "@here This is a string";
```

What I'd like to do is define a function that finds and parses this file. It can search for a string with '@here in it, then allow me to parse it.

Is this possible? I'm not sure if there's a way to search the JS file you're in for strings (the string is declared before the function, if that helps).

UPDATE:

For the record, this string is generated by TestCafe, and to my knowledge I'm not sure if there's a way for me to modify it or assign it to a variable. I haven't been able to start, because I'm not sure if there's a way to parse the document I'm in with the script itself -- (kind-of inception-like!) and I wanted to see if there was anyway to do it.

If anyone is familiar with TestCafe-centric solution as well, that would be great!

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from assigning that string to a variable?

Comment: This is (probably) a nonsensical thing to want to do. There is almost certainly a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do, if you tell us we can probably suggest it.

Comment: Sounds like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Are we talking quines here? : ) 

http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

Comment: Well, the string is generated by the server and I have no real ability to assign it as a varible

Comment: Also, please don't downvote! Just wanted to see if it was possible. I'm not sure where to start with this :(

Comment: Why do you need to do this, instead of setting vars in the file that will explicitly indicate state, contents, etc?  If you were injecting your code into another code, then you would already have a handle on the file to search.... so it seems that you have control of the JS file that you're looking to analyze.

Comment: Correction -- part of the code file I'm using is auto-generated, and that is the part with the '@' character. I know it will be inserted, but I have no control over how it is placed there (at least to my knowledge). I'm using TextCafe if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the surface, I'd recommend

1. using the name of the file to
2. re-request it from the server,
3. store it into a string var
4. search through that string